# Js push value to object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have the following object array

```
 datasets: [{
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#4BC0C0",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#E7E9ED",
        "#36A2EB"
    ],
    label: 'My dataset' // for legend
}],
labels: []
};
```

and i have another object array like bellow

```
[
{
"PORT": "MY",
"Country Name": "AUSTRALIA",
"nocontainers": "1017"
},
{
"PORT": "MY"
"Country Name": "CAMBODIA",
"nocontainers": "1"
},
{
"PORT": "DE"
"Country Name": "CHINA",
"nocontainers": "13846"
},
{
"PORT": "DE"
"Country Name": "HONG KONG",
"nocontainers": "252"
},
{
"PORT": "MY"
"Country Name": "INDONESIA",
"nocontainers": "208"
}
```

what i want to is to push all the value from 'nocontainers' to 'data' key and value from 'Country Name' to 'labels' key in first array.

i have tried array.push but didn't work, my final array should look like bellow

```
 datasets: [{
    data: [1017, 1, 13846, 252, 208],
    backgroundColor: [
        "#FF6384",
        "#4BC0C0",
        "#FFCE56",
        "#E7E9ED",
        "#36A2EB"
    ],
    label: 'My dataset' // for legend
}],
labels: ["AUSTRALIA (MY)","CAMBODIA (MY)","CHINA (DE)","HONG KONG (DE)","INDONESIA (MY)"]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your object using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull out the required properties from your `countries` object.

See working example below:

```js
const countries = [{PORT:"MY","Country Name":"AUSTRALIA",nocontainers:"1017"},{PORT:"MY","Country Name":"CAMBODIA",nocontainers:"1"},{PORT:"DE","Country Name":"CHINA",nocontainers:"13846"},{PORT:"DE","Country Name":"HONG KONG",nocontainers:"252"},{PORT:"MY","Country Name":"INDONESIA",nocontainers:"208"}];

const obj = {
  datasets: {
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: ["#FF6384", "#4BC0C0", "#FFCE56", "#E7E9ED", "#36A2EB"],
    label: 'My dataset'
  },
  labels: []
};

obj.datasets.data = countries.map(({nocontainers: nc}) => +nc);
obj.labels = countries.map(({"Country Name": cn, PORT: p}) => `${cn} (${p})`);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Note that he wanted to change original object, maybe you should provide an alternative example: `obj.datasets.data = countries.map(...)` and `obj.labels = countries.map(...)`. Anyway +1!

Comment: what if i want to combined new port value to country object in brackets?

Comment: @Eliteuser I don't really understand your question. Pease **edit** your question (leaving the original untouched) with your updated question, providing the expected output.

Comment: @Shidersz thanks, I decided to change my original answer :)

Comment: @NickParsons sorry about that. i was just thinking what is i want to 'PORT' value to be displayed in front of in new array like this labels: ["AUSTRALIA (MY)","CAMBODIA (MY)","CHINA (DE)","HONG KONG (DE)","INDONESIA (MY)"]

Comment: @Eliteuser I see now. I've updated my answer. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  datasets: {
    data: [],
    backgroundColor: [
      "#FF6384",
      "#4BC0C0",
      "#FFCE56",
      "#E7E9ED",
      "#36A2EB"
    ],
    label: 'My dataset' // for legend
  },
  labels: []
}
let arr = [{
    "Country Name": "AUSTRALIA",
    "nocontainers": "1017"
  },
  {
    "Country Name": "CAMBODIA",
    "nocontainers": "1"
  },
  {
    "Country Name": "CHINA",
    "nocontainers": "13846"
  },
  {
    "Country Name": "HONG KONG",
    "nocontainers": "252"
  },
  {
    "Country Name": "INDONESIA",
    "nocontainers": "208"
  }
]
arr.forEach(a => {
  data.datasets.data.push(a['nocontainers'])
  data.labels.push(a['Country Name'])
})
console.log(data)
```